# In the year 2020, why do we still get prompted to restart our computer after installing software?

Tags: windows, installation

Did it ever really make a difference? I haven't restarted after an install in nearly 15 years if I'm honest. What have I been missing out on? Keep in mind I mean simple software, not huge drivers, operating system updates, or major downloads like that.

Comment: in general you need to restart your pc because some files can't be modified when the system is running. "why it's necessary for small programs" is a very broad question and would require investigation of each program to decide whether it's really needed or overkill. Anyway we can't usefully answer this question on this site.

Comment: Some Registry changes do not go into effect until restart is the main reason windows needs to restart and Linux does not.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you run a program, it launches into memory and a lock is created on the program itself until the program ends. This means, that nothing can alter that program.

When you update a normal program, the installer will tell you the program needs to be closed before it can be updated. You click next, the program closes and updates and is restarted. If the program was not launched, it will not ask that, and perform the update normally.

Given that a program cannot update itself, either you download a newer version from the website using an installer and run that, or the program has a separate program that updates the main program. The program cannot update itself as it cannot close itself and then execute additional code.

It is the same principle why an entire OS needs to be restarted when performing OS updates.

An OS is a collection of many programs, of which many are run during uptime. Some of these programs can safely be closed for an update, but many programs are dependend on eachother meaning that in some cases, the OS just needs to be put into a different state where only the updater program is running in order to update the entire system. This is also why nowadays some OS updates don't require a restart anymore. This is the case for all major Operating systems, Windows, Mac and Linux included.

Some software will still ask you to restart after the installation. This is basically due to the usage of shared libraries. The software installs/updates a collection of files that it depends on, and if a file was in use during the installation, it is queued to be updated on the next reboot. In some most cases, these shared libraries already exist on the system, possibly a different version, but will run regardless. In these cases, the system will still ask for a reboot, but the software will run regardless.

So, TL;DR: An OS is a collection of programs, and in order to update a program it needs to be closed. Some programs are mandatory to the user so if these programs need to be closed, the entire OS needs to be shut down, hench the OS restarts to an update state in order to perform updates.

Comment: It does seem that Windows suffers from this more than Mac. The only app I can recall that needs a reboot these days is Little Snitch, which needs to load before login. Other than that I cannot remember how long it is since I had to reboot for anything other than an OS update.

Comment: @Tetsujin true. I've seen a few apps on mac in the past that when you update them through the app store require a reboot. But honestly it has been 3 years ago when I saw that. I forgot what app it was...